# If date is null (SQL Server CE)

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to query a table with a `status` column and a `DateSent` column. In my query, I want to combine these two columns into one `sent` column - so that if the status is `c` (closed/sent), then display the `DateSent` - but if not, then display the appropriate status.

Any row that is not `sent`, will have `DateSent` as NULL.

Desired output below:

```
ID     Sent
-----------------
1      Queued
2      Failed
3      2013-02-28
4      Queued
```

My current SQL Server CE query:

```
select 
    ID, DateAdded, 
    case when DateSent is null then 
      (case when Status='W' then 'Waiting' else 
       case when Status='O' then 'Uploaded' else 
       case when Status='F' then 'Failed' else 
       case when Status='E' then 'Expired' else 
       'Unknown' end end end end) else DateSent 
    end as Sent 
from table
```

But the `else DateSent` part on line 7 is throwing an error:

> *There was a syntax error in the date format. [0, 0, 0,Expression: Failed,,]*

Could someone help with how I might get around this problem?

Edit: An easier-to-read snippet of the problem is:

```
select case when DateSent is null
then 'null' else DateSent --<---- problem is here
end as Sent from table
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. I misread. But why do you have it so complicated? You can do the same with one `CASE` expression.

Comment: @ypercube I started learning SQL about a month ago, so I'm not too familiar with the easiest/most efficient way of doing things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this; (you may need to convert DateSent to nvarchar)

```
 select ID, 
        DateAdded, 
        case when DateSent is null
             then (case status when 'W' then 'Waiting'  
                               when 'O' then 'Uploaded'  
                               when 'F' then 'Failed'  
                               when 'E' then 'Expired' 
                                        else 'Unknown' 
                   end)
             else  convert(nvarchar(30), DateSent) 
        end as Sent
from table
```

Comment: With this query I get the error: `Invalid argument to date encode` - when you say "convert DateSent to varchar" - do you mean convert the input in the query? Or convert the column's data type? (I really don't want to do the latter)

Comment: Not the field datatype :). In output of datesent in the else part of case. In sql sever it is 'convert(varchar(30), datesent)' not sure about CE syntax.

Comment: Aha! That worked! For CE, it needs to be 'nvarchar' instead of 'varchar'. Please add as answer and I will accept/upvote :)

Comment: Done ! I'm on my mobile, bit diff to type. tnx